# NSGA-II code help in R for integer max/min problem

Tags: r, optimization

I'm trying to run NSGA-II function in R. It's a hockey team selection problem. I have a set of player data called Ducks and two objective functions, one for maximising the other for minimising. These are goals scored and goals conceded.

My understanding is that everything put into NSGA-II has to be for minimisation, so I have used the negative of the goals scored function instead.

I'm having some trouble getting it to work. Here is some code.

```
#TEST
#Load libraries
library(mco)
library(dplyr)
library(MASS)

# Calculate the total goals scored
#For f1, the second line counts the number of unique players and sets the max value of i to that
#the third line is the function
fitness <- function(x){
  
  #assign weight to each player (weight = amount of player selected)
  weight_player <- x

f1 <- numeric()
for (i in 1:n_distinct(Ducks$Player)) {
  f1[i] <- weight_player[i]*Ducks$SummaryGls[i]
}
mean_goals <- -sum(f1) 

# Calculate the total goals allowed
f2 <- numeric()
for (i in 1:n_distinct(Ducks$Player)) {
  f2[i] <- weight_player[i]*Ducks$GoalkeeperGA[i]
}
    mean_goalsA <- sum(f2)
}

#CONSTRAINTS
#Calculate the number of goalkeepers
g1 <- numeric() 
  for (i in 1:n_distinct(Ducks$Player)) {
  g1[i] <- Ducks$GK[i]
}
countgoalkeeper <- sum(g1)

#Calculate the number of players
g2 <- numeric() 
  for (i in n_distinct(Ducks$Player)) {
    g3[i] <- Ducks$GAMES[i]
  }
countplayers <- nrow(g2)
  

#Sum of goalkeepers = 1
playerconstraint1 <- sum(g1)
#Sum of all players = 11
playerconstraint2 <- sum(g2)


#Apply to NSGA-II function
nsga2(fitness,2,2,generations=500,lower.bounds=c(0,0),upper.bounds=c(1,1),constraint="countgoalkeeper")
```

I'm trying to get it to give the best teams based on player stats. ie maximise number of goals scored and minimising the number conceded, subject to constraints that there must always be 1 goalkeeper and Z many players.

This is the error i get back

```
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 
  unused argument (constraint = "countgoalkeeper")
```

It's my first time trying to use this. Besides getting it to work at all, i don't know how to make it select only integer values of players eg you can't pick half a player to play in a match.

Any pointers are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Show us a link to documentation of the ‘constraint’ parameter in whatever unnamed package you have loaded.

Comment: It's MCO: http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/web/packages/mco/mco.pdf

Comment: I get a different error: `could not find function "n_distinct"`. Perhaps you should read up on what's expected for  a [MCVE]. We expect tested code in a clean session where you know all the packages that have been loaded. The best way to do this is to line up all the library calls at the beginning of the code in a clean session and run the code you expect to be copied and pasted into our console session.Then you get the errors for the missing libraries that you have not advised us are needed.

Comment: Apologies - now done.

Comment: I'm using lower bound 0 and upper bound 1. My thought is that by restricting the weights to this, and setting a constraint that sum of weights = Z, I can get it to return either 1 or 0 for all players if they are picked. I don't want it to get (eg) 0.176 of one player and 1.325 of another.

Comment: Are you reading the error message? When you get an error saying unknown argument then it suggests you are either making up argument names, or that you are following someone else’s code and they were using a different package or a different version. There may be a different package with the same function.